# Request all reddit comments from user with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reddit

I am trying to achieve the following with Javascript:

Given a reddit username , I want to retrieve the maximum amount of comments allowed for this user.

So far what i have managed to do is retrieve only the 25 latest comments which is the default reddit behaviour. Typing  in the browser for example the following url, we receive 25 comments in the json response.

"https://www.reddit.com/user/spez/.json"

We can limit or extend the number of comments from a user ( name of user is spez in the example)  as follows:

"https://www.reddit.com/user/spez/.json?limit=1000"

However how could I also use limit with the following ?

```
$.getJSON(
       "http://www.reddit.com/u/"+ user + "/.json?jsonp=?",function foo(result) {
        $.each(result.data.children.slice(0, 10),
            function (i, post) {
              $("#reddit-content").append( '<br>' + post.data.body );
              $("#reddit-content").append( '<hr>' );
            });
        }
      )
```

Comment: append *&limit=1000* ?

Comment: Thanks! this worked...

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$.getJSON(
       "http://www.reddit.com/u/"+ user + "/.json",{ limit: 1000 },function foo(result) {
        $.each(result.data.children.slice(0, 10),
            function (i, post) {
              $("#reddit-content").append( '<br>' + post.data.body );
              $("#reddit-content").append( '<hr>' );
            });
        }
      )
```

Here's the doc: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

The signature of getJSON is url, data, success. In your call you sent in the url, and the success callback. But you can also send in data that's a plain object or a string. You can see I sent in an object { limit : 1000 }, jquery will parse that so the request will be

https://www.reddit.com/user/spez/.json?limit=1000